# Is it possible to create a target that repeats an action for different files?

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to build a Makefile that simplifies compilation for a C assignment. The Makefile works fine for now, however, I would like to add a new target that executes a previous target and creates files.

The objective is the following:

- Compile a given program (`figures.c`)
- Execute it (this creates a bunch of `.gv` files)
- Transform every .gv file to a `.pdf` file

I know how to transform a single file (I have the command), but can't seem to figure out how to loop through every file, without typing them all out.

I've already tried doing a different type of target, but does not work (see commented target)

```
# COMPILATION

CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -ansi -pedantic

# DOSSIERS

SOURCEDOC=sourcedoc
DOC=doc
SRC=src
INC=inc
OBJ=build
FIGS=images

FILES=$(wildcard $(FIGS)/*.gv)

.PHONY: clean doc archive author all

.SILENT : clean


#                  Targets

all : clean test images

test : $(OBJ)/Test_arbre.o $(OBJ)/aux.o $(OBJ)/Affichage.o $(OBJ)/ArbreBinaire.o $(OBJ)/arbres.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

figures : $(OBJ)/figures.o $(OBJ)/Affichage.o $(OBJ)/ArbreBinaire.o $(OBJ)/aux.o $(OBJ)/arbres.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

%.pdf: $(FIGS)/%.gv
    dot -Tpdf -o $(FIGS)/$@ $^

#$(FILES): $(FIGS)/%.pdf : $(FIGS)/%.gv
#   dot -Tpdf -o $@ $^

images : figures $(FILES)

#=========== Objets ===========

$(OBJ)/arbres.o : $(INC)/arbres.h $(INC)/aux.h $(INC)/Affichage.h $(INC)/ArbreBinaire.h

$(OBJ)/Affichage.o : $(INC)/Affichage.h $(INC)/ArbreBinaire.h

$(OBJ)/exemple*_arbre.o : $(INC)/Affichage.h $(INC)/ArbreBinaire.h

$(OBJ)/aux.o : $(INC)/aux.h

$(OBJ)/figures.o : $(INC)/Affichage.h $(INC)/ArbreBinaire.h $(INC)/arbres.h

$(OBJ)/Test_arbre.o : $(INC)/arbres.h $(INC)/ArbreBinaire.h $(INC)/Affichage.h


#                  Dummy rule

$(OBJ)/%.o : $(SRC)/%.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @$(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) -I $(INC)/ -c -o $@


#                 Miscellaneous

clean:
    rm -f *~ */*~
    rm -rf __pycache__ src/__pycache__
    rm -rf $(DOC)
    rm -f $(PROJECT)_$(AUTHOR12)_$(AUTHOR22).zip
    rm -f conf.py-e
    rm -rf $(OBJ)
    rm -f $(FIGS)/*.pdf $(FIGS)/*.gv
    rm -f test
```

The current Makefile works fine on all other commands than images.

If any of you could help, it would mean a lot!

Comment: `FILES=$(FIGS)/*.gv` This is wrong, because (1) '*' is not wildcard here, it's just an asterisk; (2) *.gv files are expected to be created on make's pass, so they might not exist on startup; (3) images should depend on *.pdf files, not on *.gv files.

Comment: How could I be able to change that ?

Comment: Get rid of wildcards and write file names explicitly.

Comment: Do you know the file names before you run Make?

Comment: I do know the file names, but there are quite a lot of them (30-40), so I was hoping to automate it. That way, if I were to add a couple of files with the program, it would work first try. Currently I have to run make twice for it to take the file names into consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `FILES` should map the `*.gv` files to the corresponding `*.pdf` files;

```
FILES=$(patsubst %.gv,%.pdf,$(wildcard $(FIGS)/*.gv))
```

The rule which says how to generate a PDF should factor out the directory name;

```
%.pdf: %.gv
    dot -Tpdf -o $@ $^
```

Now, if `make` tries to create `$(FIGS)/ick.pdf`, the input will be `$(FIGS)/ick.gv` - the pattern says to substitute the extension `.gv` with the extension `.pdf`, and the rest of the file name stays unmodified, exactly like you'd want. A rule like

```
%.pdf: $(FIGS)/%.gv  # error, don't use
```

says you need to find the source file in a subdirectory `$(FIGS)`; so if you tried to make `$(FIGS)/ick.pdf`, that means `make` would need to find or generate `$(FIGS)/$(FIGS)/ick.gv` as input according to this rule.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely cannot predict what files will be created on step (2) (and so confined to using `$(wildcard ...)`), you still must execute it *after* (2) is finished.

It's ugly but I can't think of better alternative than using "recursive make". I mean something like this:

```
...
.PHONY: images pdf
images: figures
    # use figures to generate all .gv files
    #@figures --create-all-gv-files
    # invoke make recursively
    @$(MAKE) --no-print-directory pdf

# ensure $(wildcard ...) is invoked only if needed
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),pdf)
    PDF_FILES:=$(patsubst %.gv,%.pdf,$(wildcard $(FIGS)/*.gv))
endif

pdf: $(PDF_FILES)
%.pdf: %.gv
    dot -Tpdf -o $@ $<
```